# How do I use jquery's animate method to make a div move back and forth

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to make a div  animate horizontally back and forth within a certain area. The problem I have right now is that I can't figure out how to make my div move back after it has moved forward.

Here is the script that I am using:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var animatethis = function (targetElement, speed) {
        $(targetElement).animate(
            {
                marginLeft: "+=250px"
            },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    animatethis(this, speed);
                    animatethis.stop();
                    $(targetElement).animate({ marginLeft: "-=250px" });
                }
            }
                    )
    };
    animatethis($('#q1'), 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: You just need a callback after first animation, try my answer.

Comment: Yes i wanted it to loop sorry if i did not make this clear

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look in your browser console. `animatethis` does not return anything, which means that the line

```
animatethis.stop();
```

is always going to crash (something like "TypeError: Cannot call method 'stop' of undefined"). You're also mixing up the order of the animations in the `complete` callback.

Stop, breathe, and think about what your code above is actually doing.

---

Okay, so after the `marginLeft` is increased, you want to decrease it. *Then* you want to start all over. Right? So:

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
    $(targetElement).animate({ marginLeft: "+=250px"},
    {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function ()
        {
            targetElement.animate({ marginLeft: "-=250px" },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function ()
                {
                    animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                }
            });
        }
    });
};

animatethis($('#q1'), 5000);
```

There are lots of other ways to skin this cat, but this does work. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/rKu6Y/

Comment: Wow thanks that was just what I needed and yeah when I was using stop it was printing stuff to the output panel

Comment: I wonder why it does not trigger a stack overflow exception, as this is essentially an infinite recursion.

Comment: @Neolisk callbacks don't keep adding to the stack – they're called later.

Answer (score 8):

Are you trying to do this? http://jsfiddle.net/vwH6R/2/

```
setInterval(function(){
    $("div").stop(true,true).animate({left: 300}, 1000, 
          function(){ $(this).stop(true,true).animate({left: 0}, 1000); 
    });
}, 2000);​
```

Comment: This one is the best.

Answer (score 3):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/A6BXk/) fiddle

**HTML**

```
<div class="myDiv">A Div</div>​
```

**JS**

```
$('.myDiv').animate({
   'margin-left':'50px'
}, 500, function(e){
$('.myDiv').animate({
    'margin-left':'0px'
}, 500)});​
```

Comment: I think the OP wanted the animation to loop. Perhaps I'm wrong.

Comment: Thanks but I thought that he just wanted to do it move forward and back it again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to move it back-and-forth for a number of times, you could wrap it up into a function, that calls itself. Something like this:

```
function wobble(selector, amount, times, intSpeed) {

    var string = String($(selector).css("marginLeft")).replace("px", ""),
    leftMargin = parseInt(string, 10);

    $(selector).animate({ marginLeft: (leftMargin + amount) + 'px' }, intSpeed, function () {
        if (times > 0) {
            wobble(selector, -amount, --times, intSpeed);
        } else {
            $(selector).css("marginLeft", leftMargin + 'px');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery `queue()` method to chain events : http://api.jquery.com/queue/